# Excel custom format url column with a tags

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of url's with contents like this

`http://www.mysite.com/page1`

`http://www.mysite.com/page2`

I need a formula in excel where I can add an `a` tag before and after each url, so the result is like this:

`<a href="http://www.mysite.com/page1" class="url">Origin URL</a>`

`<a href="http://www.mysite.com/page2" class="url">Origin URL</a>`

I saw this article here which explains how to add quotes around a text in excel however it didn't work and I couldn't find anything else that suits my needs

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100210103758AAsTyfK

Any help is greatly appreciated, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `Concatenate` function

If your URL is in Cell A1, put this in B1:

```
=CONCATENATE("<a href=""",A1,"""> class=""url"">Origin URL</a>")
```

(Note the quotes are escaped by repeating them.)

You can then fill this formula down to rows below to cover all of your column of URLs

Comment: what if I have a whole column of cells in column A? Do I simply drag this function all the way down?

Comment: Okay I tried that and it didn't work, so apparently I need to run this function in a separate cell, not over the same one in A1. Now I just need to have this function work for A1-A15

Comment: Yes, you need an empty helper column to run this formula. But after you're done with this, you can just copy&paste your helper column right over your original column with `Insert » Paste special » values`

Comment: Yes, sorry, the formula should go in B1 and be filled down